# How can I suppress "WARN: 'Could not find HammerJS." on each text execution?

Tags: angular, hammer.js, angular-material2

When executing tests, each test logs the following:

```
WARN: 'Could not find HammerJS. Certain Angular Material components may not work correctly.'
```

From from [Angular Material Getting Started Guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started):

> Some components (`md-slide-toggle`, `md-slider`, `mdTooltip`) rely on HammerJS for gestures. In order to get the full feature-set of these components, HammerJS must be loaded into the application.

Based on that, my conclusion is that I don't need HammerJS installed as I'm not specifically using the Angular Material components that require it. *If you don't need it, don't add it!*

But whilst executing 1000+ tests, having that warning print out each time really isn't helpful and so I want to get rid of it or have it print once only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution will:

1. Warn about the lack of HammerJS once only.
2. Print an error to the console if you ever end up using the `new Hammer()` constructor in the future.
3. Not require you to call `enableProdMode()` within your test environment so you can continue to benefit from the additional error checking that double change detection provides.

Add the following `beforeAll` function to your test bundle:

```
beforeAll(function() {
    if (!window.hasOwnProperty('Hammer')) {
        window['Hammer'] = function() {
            console.error(
                'HammerJS is not installed. If you\'re now using Angular Material components that require it, please "npm i hammerjs"'
            );
        };
        console.warn('Could not find HammerJS. Certain Angular Material components may not work correctly.');
    }
});
```